# How to remove/enable android default keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard

I have 2 questions that I would be greatful if anyone could help me with. I wanna implement a options menu in my app that gives the user the possibility to remove the default keyboard in the app and aswell trun it on again if needed.

How do you implement this in android, all I can find is code-examples where you remove the keyboard for a certain edittext, but I want it disabled all the time, or enabled all the time?.

My second question is, if you wanna create a input for a editbox which only allows input values between 0-36 ( numbers ), what shall I use then if not using the keyboard as input option ? I am thinking of some sort of scroll with numbers 0-36 ?. This should be the other option from my options menu in the app ( this function will replace the default keyboard ).

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First, do not ask two completely unrelated questions in a single StackOverflow entry.

> I wanna implement a options menu in my app that gives the user the possibility to remove the default keyboard in the app and aswell trun it on again if needed.

Sorry, that is not possible.

> I am thinking of some sort of scroll with numbers 0-36 ?

You could use a `SeekBar`, or a `NumberPicker` on Android 3.0.